# What is better HTML code for this

Tags: html, performance, optimization

What is better HTML code :

case 1 :

```
<body bgcolor=" #000000" width="100%" height="100%">
</body>
```

case 2 :

```
<body>
<img src="black.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</body>
```

seems case 1 wins or css is best option
Thanks.
Sorry guys i have edited my question again.

Its like this :

What is better HTML code :

case 1 :

```
<body bgcolor="<!--Is there a color combination code for a photograph/any css approach ?? -->" width="100%" height="100%">
</body>
```

case 2 :

```
<body>
<img src="your_photo.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</body>
```

Well, I am all this doing because image is too large in size and internet speed is very low.I guess twitter also does it when we set themes(*not sure*)

Comment: You are using many style attributes, and that's not encouraged in modern HTML.

Comment: FYI: `#FFF` is the code for `white`. I only mention this because your image is for `black.jpg`

Comment: @AgentConundrum you're totally right. Edited to make it make sense. :)

Comment: @Pratik: because HTML stands for "HyperText Markup Language", it's generally used to store data, and CSS as "Cascaded Style Sheet", manages the style. Separating them produce easier code for maintenance and reading.

Comment: @Pratik: FYI, the style attributes are also removed in latest XHTML standards.

Comment: @ryanli ya may be because more than 1 person was editing the same post.But to my knowledge this even if it doesn't fit into some standards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is better:

```
<body>
...
</body>
```

and in an external CSS style:

```
body {
    background: #000 url('black.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: wait what ?! If black.jpg is what I think it is, shouldn't it be "background-color: black;" ? Weird question

Comment: @Thomas Joulin, yes it probably should, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general the css would be preferred for performance (its faster to load CSS than load an image).

Answer (score 0):

The CSS would be faster, and would yield less wasted bandwidth on the hosting end for a high traffic site.

Answer (score 0):

you can set background using CSS instead of loading images everytime into your HTML document, it will help in many cases

as you are using css you won't need to load the image everytime you can set an image background to any class while loading the page it won't load each time but it'll load the page and have the image as its background

```
<body> </body>
```

and in a CSS file(external) use

```
        body
       {     
           background-image: xx.jpg;
         }
```

avoid using the  tag for simplicity purpose use external CSS files to classify the CSS codes

and also avoid

this is totally horrendous when you have to style a very complex site, if you go on styling each and every element in the HTML code itself, at a later stage you'll have to start again from scratch!